# How to use jquery ui with bower?

Tags: jquery-ui, yeoman, bower

I'm experimenting with [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and [bower](http://bower.io/).

I have created a yeoman webapp using the following command

```
yo webapp
```

I want to use [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/) so I have installed it using bower:

```
bower install jquery-ui --save
```

This works fine, but the jQuery UI component doesn't contain a javascript file with "all" the components, it just contains a lot of javascript files, one for each component.

Should I include only the javascript files that I need? Or should I do something else before using jQuery UI?

Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 17):

Added `jquery-ui` in `dependencies` of `bower.json` (or `component.json`) along with `jquery`.

```
{
  …,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.10.3",
    ...
  },
  …
}
```

Install them:

```
bower install
```

Then, added path to `jqueryui` In `main.js` and require it:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: '../components/jquery/jquery',
    jqueryui: '../components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui',
    …
  },
  shim: {
    jqueryui: 'jquery',
    …
  },
  …
});
require(['app', 'jquery', 'jqueryui', 'bootstrap'], function (app, $) {
  'use strict';
   ...
});
```

It works for me.

Comment: The OP didn't mention require.js

Answer (score 5):

In the latest jQuery UI bower component as we speak (v. 1.10.3), you can do the following:

1. For the CSS themes, include the following link:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components_path/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`
2. To get the most components and widgets of jQueryUI running, include the following script:

   `<script src="bower_components_path/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js" ></script>`

Answer (score 5):

For reference, `bower install jquery-ui --save` would add the `jquery-ui.js` dependency to the project, but not the styles. For that I needed to add to the `bower.json` file an `overrides` section, as below

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "jquery-ui": "^1.11.4" // already added with --save from bower install command
  },
  ...,
  "overrides": {
    "jquery-ui": {
      "main": [
        "themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css",
        "jquery-ui.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27419553/4126114

https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep/issues/86

Comment: using wiredep's `overrides` also works nicely if you want a custom build of jquery-ui

Answer (score 3):

I would just include the files that I need or use the default custom build in the folder (which I believe has all the components) if you require everything or if it's just for experimentation.

```
<script src="components/jqueryui/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js"></script>
```

At this time bower pulls down the entire repo and since (from their website) "bower is just a package manager" anything else needed like concatenation or module loading is handled by other tools like sprockets/requirejs.

**References:**

Using packages with bower on homepage http://bower.io/

Dissusion about bower and pulling entire repos
https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/45

Comment: great post! the idea of bower is great but it lacks definitly a way of delivering a whole package of a library (even if the project doesn't compile into a single resource). until now bower is a nightmare :)

Comment: That jquery-ui.custom.js does not exist anymore as of 1.10.2.  I suppose you need some grunt task to build that?

Answer (score -2):

You could use requirejs.config's shim property to achieve your goal:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'jquery.ui.sortable': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jquery.ui.core', 'jquery.ui.widget', 'jquery.ui.mouse', 'jquery.ui.position'],
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});
```

We specified, that jquery.ui.sortable, when required in your project, needs to load and execute the modules listed under `deps` first, before being executed itself.

Unfortunately, this still produces a race condition... But that is generally how one would go about this (:

Comment: I Don't think jquery.ui.position is a requirement of jquery.ui.sortable.

Comment: Actually, the documentation doesn't mention jquery.ui.position is required, but it most certainly is!

Comment: The OP didn't mention require.js