# Getting npm to install a given version of jquery [unable to find jquery buttonset]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, yeoman

I am trying to use buttonset from jquery, according to the jquery web site [http://jqueryui.com/] buttonset is defined in version 1.8.7

My yeoman build web site seems to have version jQuery Javascript Library v1.9.1 [taken from bower_components/jquery.js] dated 2013-2-4

I have done an npm update so I assume I am on the latest version

A find bower_components -exec grep -i buttonset '{}' ';' does not find a refference to buttonset, neither does a javascript web application built under yeoman.
I have downloaded the latest version of jquery and that does have buttonset defined in a css  file, the version in bower_components only seems to have css files  app/bower_components/jquery/speed/benchmark.css and app/bower_components/jquery/test/data/testsuite.css

So
What version of jquery do I need to download to get buttonset?
How do I get npm/yeoman etc to down load a given version of jquery?
How do I find out which version of jquery npm has actuall downloaded?
Is the version of jquery downloaded by npm missing some css files?

I could resolve this problem by installing my own version of jquery, but that seems to be wrong and would only lead to trouble with having two version of the same library in the same application

Any suggestions greatfully accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my setup was missing the jquery ui part

See [How to use jquery ui with bower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284292/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-bower) for how to solve it